# UK extended family visa question

Tags: visas, uk, algerian-citizens

My cousin that lives in the UK is the grandson of my father's uncle. Basically, my father and my cousin are very close friends, and me being my father's son, my cousin wants to invite me to the UK.

Can I use our extended family relationship to get a family-based visa? I have all the papers that prove we're related.

Should I instead apply for a standard visitor visa with my cousin giving me a formal invitation? I plan to initially go for a 15 day trip, then go on a longer visit later. If the first visa doesn't allow multiple entries, can I invalidate (cancel) the visa once I return home and apply for a new, longer visa?

Comment: Not sure how this qualifies as an extended family member situation? Or what you mean by ‘invalidate your visa’?

Comment: So, this man is your second cousin.  What is his citizenship?  And what is yours?

Comment: Invalidate my Visa means that I'll be having one single entry in my 6months period Visa. (Traveller)

Comment: Nate Eldredge 1/he's a UK citizen (has an NHS number) 2/I'm Algerian.

Comment: "I ignore if going for a standard visitor Visa with a formal invitation would be more incentive vis-à-vis the fluency that the UK border control will provide me with on the "leave to enter"s situations" I'm sorry but I have no idea what this is supposed to mean. It would probably help if you tried to rephrase it using simpler words and grammatical constructions.

Comment: @David richerby : the phrases after i.e. repeat the same info.

Comment: You aren't a close enough relative to get any type of a "family" visa/permit. Even if your cousin sponsors you, you still need a stable life/job in Algeria that will convince the border control agent that you will return to Algeria.

Answer (score 2):

The [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit) is for family members citizens of EEA countries *other than the UK* (except under limited circumstances that do not apply here).  Furthermore, "extended family members" only qualify if they are either dependent on the principal or are members of the principal's household.

You therefore do not qualify for an EEA family permit for two reasons.  First, because your cousin is a citizen of the UK rather than another EU or EEA country or Switzerland, and second because you are not close enough to qualify as a family member, and your circumstances do not qualify you as an extended family member.  You should get a [standard visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) for this trip.